# Find text in webview page using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How can I find text in uiwebview page and highlight it and go to its position in the page using swift ?

For example chrome find text :

[search example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy7DC.png)

But I'm using alert view instead :

[my search example in my app !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lzm0.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use JavaScript for this.
 
I done the same thing with code below (but in Objective C - you can rewrite it to Swift).

Usage (only in webViewDidFinishLoad - it's important!):

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (self.searchString != nil ) {
        [self.webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:self.searchString];
        int position = self.foundedStringsCount - self.selectedStringNumber - 1;
        [self.webView scrollTo:position];
    }
}
```

Create and add this files to your code:

SearchWebView.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SearchWebView : UIWebView

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)scrollTo:(int)index;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;

@end
```

SearchWebView.m:

```
#import "SearchWebView.h"

@implementation SearchWebView

- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

    NSString *startSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

    NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_SearchResultCount"];
    return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)scrollTo:(int)index {
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_ScrollTo('%d')",index]];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}

@end
```

UIWebViewSearch.js:

```
var uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;

/*!
 @method     uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement
 @abstract   // helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes
 @discussion // helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes

 element    - HTML elements
 keyword    - string to search
 */

function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node

            var count = 0;
            var elementTmp = element;
            while (true) {
                var value = elementTmp.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;

                count++;
                elementTmp = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
            }

            uiWebview_SearchResultCount += count;

            var index = uiWebview_SearchResultCount;
            while (true) {
                var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

                //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
                span.appendChild(text);

                span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
                span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                span.style.color="black";

                index--;
                span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+(index));
                //span.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

                //element.parentNode.setAttribute("id", "SEARCH WORD"+uiWebview_SearchResultCount);

                //uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter

                text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);

                var next = element.nextSibling;
                //alert(element.parentNode);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                element = text;
            }


        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights();
    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}

// helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
            if (element.getAttribute("class") == "uiWebviewHighlight") {
                var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                return true;
            } else {
                var normalize = false;
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                        normalize = true;
                    }
                }
                if (normalize) {
                    element.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// the main entry point to remove the highlights
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights() {
    uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
}

function uiWebview_ScrollTo(idx) {
    var scrollTo = document.getElementById("SEARCH WORD" + idx);
    if (scrollTo) scrollTo.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Better to check whether ___keyword___ parameter is null or empty  in ___uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString___ function like this,
___uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights(); 
if (keyword) { uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase()); }___

Answer (score 3):

Here is the swift code:

1) add UIWebViewSearch.js file to your project

```
func highlightAllOccurencesOfString(str:String) -> Int {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js")

    var jsCode = ""

    do{

        jsCode = try String(contentsOfFile: path!)

    }catch
    {
    // do something

    }

    self.newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsCode)

    let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(str)')"

    self.newsWebView .stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)

    let  result = self.newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "uiWebview_SearchResultCount")

    return  Int(result!)!


}

func scrollTo(index:Int)  {

    self.newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "uiWebview_ScrollTo('\(index)')")

}

func removeAllHighlights() {

self.newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()")

}
```

Comment: Can you please update this solution for Swift 4, WKWebView? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A javascript file may be injected using WKUserContentController, as described in https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405

Since uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) is called recursively, the index for the matched text may not be unique. As seen in https://github.com/sstahurski/SearchWKWebView/blob/master/WKWebView%20Extention/SearchWebView.js, we can replace it with a global variable. So uiWebview_ScrollTo(idx) can work correctly.

And javascript functions can be run as needed by subscribing to publishers corresponding to the search text and the index for matched text.

[search field with Stepper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQU17.png)

Here is my implementation of makeNSView(context:) in NSViewRepresentable, wherein the javascript file is added to WKWebView and subscribers are attached to search text and index.

```
func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        // Add a javascript file to WKUserContentController
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"), let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
            let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
            let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jsString, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
            userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
            configuration.userContentController = userContentController
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.load(request)
        webView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Observe the text to search
        viewModel.$searchString
            .sink {
                if !$0.isEmpty {
                    
                    let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\($0)')"
                    
                    webView.find($0) { result in
                        if result.matchFound {
                            webView.evaluateJavaScript(startSearch) { result, error in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print("uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString: \(String(describing: error))")
                                    return
                                }

                                // Get the total number of matches
                                webView.evaluateJavaScript("uiWebview_SearchResultTotalCount") { result, error in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print("uiWebview_SearchResultTotalCount: \(String(describing: error))")
                                        return
                                    }
                                    
                                    if let result = result as? Int {
                                        viewModel.searchResultTotalCount = result
                                        viewModel.searchResultCounter = 1
                                        webView.evaluateJavaScript("uiWebview_ScrollTo(\(result))")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    viewModel.searchResultTotalCount = 0
                    viewModel.searchResultCounter = 0
                     
webView.evaluateJavaScript("uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()")
                }
            }
            .store(in: &viewModel.subscriptions)
        // Observe the index to scroll to
        viewModel.$searchResultCounter
            .sink {
                let index = viewModel.searchResultTotalCount - $0 + 1
                
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("uiWebview_ScrollTo(\(index))")
            }
            .store(in: &viewModel.subscriptions)
        
        return webView
    }
```