# How to Find and Highlight Text in WebView using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

I'm working on my first app, and it involves searching for a specific string of text from a large amount of text on a website.  I want to be able to search for a specific string and highlight all instances, and as the user types more, it will automatically update the highlighted occurrences. Similar to a find function in any browser.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317747/find-text-in-webview-page-using-swift) question on here where they reference using UIWebViewSearch.js to implement this, but I'm not sure how to add that file to my project, or how to use it.

I've added a search bar to my app so far, but haven't done anything with it. Want to use this function along with the search bar to search for the text.

Here is my ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Place custom HTML onto the screen
    let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myHTML", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)


    // Code that provides a string containing
    // JS code, ready to add to a webview.
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"),
        let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsString)
    } // end if


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked() {
        let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(str)')"

        self.newsWebView .stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)
    }


} // end of viewDidLoad


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} // end of didReceiveMemoryWarning


} // end of class ViewController
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what you've tried so far? Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better help you.

Comment: Again, I'm very new to Swift and Xcode. I'm not even really sure how to implement that javascript file into my program.  I'd tell you what I tried, but it has mainly been looking around the Internet for solutions, but to no avail.  The one that seemed closest to my question was the one I linked, but I don't have enough rep yet to comment, so had to ask on my own.

Comment: Requests for a "step by step" guide are probably off-topic, since they are rather broad. It is in effect a request for someone to do a large amount of work in an answer based on a question that is rather quick to type out. Have you started the app? Are you planning to use curl or similar to connect from the mobile device to the website that you're wanting to read? How much is a large amount? 50K? 50M?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jon-saw says: Welcome to StackOverflow :)

I'll just answer how you can add the JavaScript file to your project...that should get things started right :)

### Add a File

You can add a file to Xcode in several ways, but here's one.

1. In Xcode, in your project, navigate in the left hand Project navigator to where you would like to add your file.

[image: Select location]

2. Right click and select "New File..."

[image: New file]

3. Select "Empty" and click "Next"

[image]

4. Name your file `UIWebViewSearch.js` and click "Create"
5. You now have an empty file called `UIWebViewSearch.js` in your project in which you can paste in content.

### Use a File

Now you have the file on your project, so now you just need to refer to it. To do so you use [`Bundle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) which can load resources in your project for you.

If you look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317775/4063602) you referred to, you can see these lines of ObjC code in `- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Translated to Swift that would look like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"),
   let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsString)
}
```

And that should give you a `String` containing all your JS code, ready to add to a WebView for instance.

Hope that gives you something to start with.

### Update (after you added a comment to this post)

OK, so you say:

> I added my ViewController code to better communicate where I'm at. Kind of confused on how to implement the second part of his code you're referring to. Also not sure how to call the search from the searchBar. Is there a method I need to call within 'searchBarSearchButtonClicked()' method? Just found that method on the apple developer documentation, don't know if it's the correct one, though.

Lets break it down into pieces, I'll start with your `ViewController`, as there are some problems in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Place custom HTML onto the screen
    let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myHTML", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Code that provides a string containing
    // JS code, ready to add to a webview.
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"),
        let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsString)
    } // end if


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked() {
        let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(str)')"

        self.newsWebView .stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)
    }
}
```

You've added your `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` *inside* `viewDidLoad`, but it should be declared as a function by itself (we'll get back to it later).

Furthermore, as I wrote in the comments below:

> ...One part that is run when the view is loaded and which loads the JavaScript from the bundle.

So lets fix your `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Place custom HTML onto the screen
    let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myHTML", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Code that provides a string containing
    // JS code, ready to add to a webview.
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"),
        let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsString)
        //Use your jsString on the web view here.
        newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsString) 
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` function has been removed and we now use out `jsString` on the `newsWebView`.

OK, next part:

> Also not sure how to call the search from the searchBar. Is there a method I need to call within 'searchBarSearchButtonClicked()' method? Just found that method on the apple developer documentation, don't know if it's the correct one, though.

You have your `searchBarSearchButtonClicked()` method which you have found in the Apple Developer documentation, I'm guessing you're meaning [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624294-searchbarsearchbuttonclicked)

As you can see in the documentation (top bar), this function is from the [`UISearchBarDelete`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate) class.

[Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) is a design pattern used in many of Apples frameworks. It allows you to write some generic components and let "someone else" (the delegate) decide what to do with the information from the component (bad explanation I know).

Think of your `UISearchBar` for instance. If you were to implement a component that other developers could use as a search bar, how would you handle when the user searches for something? I'm thinking, how should your "customers" (the developers using your components) handle this? One way of doing this could be that the developers should subclass `UISearchBar` and override a "user did search method". You could also use `NSNotifications` and have the developer register for these notifications. Both of these methods are not pretty or clever.

Enter...the delegate.

`UISearchBar` has a `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchBarDelegate` is just a protocol as you can see. Now the `UISearchBar` can ask its delegate for certain things, or inform the delegate about important events. So for instance, when the user taps the "Search" button `UISearchBar` can call `delegate.searchBarSearchButtonClicked(self)` which means "hey delegate, the user has clicked the search button on me...just thought you should know". And the delegate can then respond as it sees fit.

This means that *any* class can conform to `UISearchBarDelegate` and handle the various tasks as it suits in their current situation.

OK, long story, hope you get the gist of it and I think you should read a bit more on delegation as it is a pattern used all over in Apples frameworks :)

So, in your case, you have a `UISearchBar`, you should give that a delegate like so:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

And you need to tell the compiler that you intend to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol. The Swift convention is to do this in an `extension` after your `ViewController`, just to keep things separated:

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

}
```

And then you must also implement the methods of `UISearchBarDelegate` that you are interested in listening to (note that some protocols have required methods, meaning that you *MUST* implement them but I don't think `UISearchBar` has (otherwise you'll find out when the app crashes the first time you run it :)).

So in your case, you mentioned `searchBarSearchButtonPressed`. As you can see it needs a `UISearchBar` as a parameter. So your function ends out looking like this:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let currentSearchText = searchBar.text else {
        return
    }
    let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(currentSearchText)')"

    newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)
}
```

So... you fetch the current text from your searchBar, add it as a parameter to your `startSearch` string and hand that `startSearch` string to your `newsWebView`.

The entire extensions ends out looking like this.

```
.... last part of your ViewController class
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } // end of didReceiveMemoryWarning
} // end of class ViewController

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let currentSearchText = searchBar.text else {
            return
        }
        let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(currentSearchText)')"

        newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)
    }
}
```

And your `viewDidLoad` ends out looking like this (you must add yourself as a delegate to the searchBar)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self //delegate set up
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Place custom HTML onto the screen
    let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myHTML", withExtension: "html")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    // Code that provides a string containing
    // JS code, ready to add to a webview.
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UIWebViewSearch", ofType: "js"),
        let jsString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsString)
        //Use your jsString on the web view here.
        newsWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: jsString) 
    }
}
```

Wow...that was a lot of writing...hope it helps you.

Comment: First of all, thank you for making things clearer.  I have added the javascript file to my project. Do I have to translate the answer you linked, or could I use the other answer from Dibin77 that seems to be in Swift? I'm using Swift, so that seems like the better option. And I'm not sure where to place the code you wrote.  Does that go somewhere in the ViewController?  I'm trying to implement a UISearchBar to search for text on a webpage. I'm sure you've used command-F before, just trying to do that with a single webpage.

Comment: @matt you can use the answer from Dibin77, I just hadn't seen it but yeah, that is easier for you. And where to put the code? You're right, you should put that in a `ViewController` that has a reference/IBOutlet to your WebView so you can attach your code to that WebView as Dibin77 does.

Comment: @matt And if you're using a `UISearchBar` I think you should consider splitting Dibin77s code from the function `highlightAllOccurencesOfString ` in two parts. One part that is run when the view is loaded and which loads the JavaScript from the bundle. And then another function that is triggered every time the user searches for a string. You then take that string and pass it to your function which does the actual search (these lines from Dibin77s code: `let startSearch = "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(str)')" self.newsWebView .stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: startSearch)`)

Comment: I added my ViewController code to better communicate where I'm at.  Kind of confused on how to implement the second part of his code you're referring to.  Also not sure how to call the search from the searchBar. Is there a method I need to call within 'searchBarSearchButtonClicked()' method?  Just found that method on the apple developer documentation, don't know if it's the correct one, though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Just a small question - when I use uiWebview_ScrollTo(idx) it scrolls to the last index of the matched text. Is there an example how to properly use the function and scroll to the matched texts starting from first index?