# Set the scroll position to search string in Xamarin.Ios

Tags: javascript, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I am working on a xamarin.ios application to show the content in a text file into webview. I could able to display the content.

Now I need to add search feature, so that the selected string needs to highlighted and SCROLL need to position in to the search text. I am using below Javascript to highlight the  searched text and highlighting is working as expected.

```
string startSearch = "MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('" + searchStr + "')";
this.webView.EvaluateJavascript (startSearch);
```

How can I move the scroll position to the searched string using this webview?

Thanks in advance

Roshil K

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code snippet to reset the scroll position of the WebView, like this:

```
    webView.ScrollView.ContentOffset = new CGPoint(0,50);
```

But you have to know the (x,y) point of the related string. I am not familiar with Javascript, maybe it can be returned by your JS code.

Also, I found a solution via JS which maybe help you here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317775/5474400.

Answer (score 0):

I got is solved by adding the below javascript to my existing "MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString" javascript.

```
var desiredHeight = span.offsetTop - 140;
window.scrollTo(0,desiredHeight);
```

My Complete Javascript is below.

```
this.webView.EvaluateJavascript ("// We're using a global variable to store the 

    number of occurrences
    var MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;

    // helper function, recursively searches in elements and their child nodes
    function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {
      if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
          while (true) {
            var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
            var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

            if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

            var span = document.createElement(\"span\");
            var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
            span.appendChild(text);
            span.setAttribute(\"class\",\"MyAppHighlight\");
            span.style.backgroundColor=\"yellow\";
            span.style.color=\"black\";
            text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
            element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
            var next = element.nextSibling;
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
            element = text;
            var desiredHeight = span.offsetTop - 140;
            window.scrollTo(0,desiredHeight);      MyApp_SearchResultCount++;\t// update the counter
          }
        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
          if (element.style.display != \"none\" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
            for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
              MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // the main entry point to start the search
    function MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
      MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights();
      MyApp_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
    }

    // helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
    function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
      if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
          if (element.getAttribute(\"class\") == \"MyAppHighlight\") {
            var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            return true;
          } else {
            var normalize = false;
            for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
              if (MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                normalize = true;
              }
            }
            if (normalize) {
              element.normalize();
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    // the main entry point to remove the highlights
    function MyApp_RemoveAllHighlights() {
      MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
      MyApp_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
    }");
```